# Footer Ignores Floating Content

Tags: css, html, footer

I need to make my footer stay on the bottom but also have it not interfere with my content.  As seen in the jfiddle, the blue box interferes with the footer.  After looking through all the current threads and trying to fix my CSS and HTML, I could not find my solution.  I tried changing the position to fixed, adding some padding, etc.  Below is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/9A2gL/8/
Basically I have:

```
<html><div id="wrapper"><header></header>
<body></body>
<footer></footer></div></html>
```

I do have floating divs but I used clearfix so `clear: both;`

**Also, please read this:** I do have a valid HTML structure but jsfiddle doesn't recommend the tags to be placed.  Please focus on the floating aspect as when I take `float:right;`in the CSS off of the .news it is working.  When I remove the code to make the footer stick at the bottom of the page, it also works.

Comment: did you try this footer{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 background-color:#58A84A;
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
 border-top:5px solid #005826;
 text-align:center;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}

Comment: Your HTML structure is completely messed up first off. All content should go in between the `<body>...</body>` tags.

Comment: Position fixed may not be exactly what he wants.

Comment: Second @LaughDonor.  Your HTML is just really wacky.  I tried cleaning it up a bit but then all your styles were funky.  Please look at the basic structure for HTML pages and how divs are used.

Comment: Dude, this HTML is garbage. No browser would run that. Thats your first problem. Second, where is your CSS that you tagged?

Comment: Not trying to be mean, but I hope you weren't trying to test your HTML on animals, because that too would not be helpful to your cause.

Comment: @Kevin O'Brien I'm not sure which styles you found "funky", but most of the fiddle looked decent enough to work from, at least for me. Whether it solves the posters issues is a different story.

Comment: @Brendan, if you took time to review the fiddle posted, you could see associated CSS. I would agree, however, the HTML and CSS should have been posted on this forum, but the fiddle at least shows time and effort to DEMONSTRATE the issue.

Comment: Then I apologize, first off, I was unnecessarily rude and did not take the time to see the jsfiddle before i posted that. i  am currently working on the issue right now. Apology in advance.

Comment: For starters, to know for sure if your HTML will run correctly, I recommend using the w3c Markup Validation Service, which will parse all of your HTML and CSS and will give you feed back on your formatting. This service was designed to make your code able to run on all major browsers. Here is the link: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Brendan The jsfiddle doesn't allow me to post html and head tags, but I have them in my code.  For some reason when I try to put `` in stackoverflow the code option doesn't pop up.

Comment: @Baig Tried that already in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clearfix div should be added before the end div of container.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML Mark is Messed Please first of all W3C Stabdards, and correct your HTML Markup some thing like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
      <header></header>
      <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Sencond for your footer please apply clearfix class there after proper markup or just

```
.Clear{
   clear:both;
}
```

You are good to go (y).

Comment: ++ for the HTML5 standard markup! Also, He has a clearfix class running `.clearfix{ clear:both; width:100%;}` immediately before the footer

Comment: @Kashif I am not allowed to include html marks in the jsfiddle; when I try to put it, it doesn't allow me to save.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it was a fiddle (THANK YOU!), but your HTML tags are out of place. That being said, the image I see from your fiddle is as follows

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="container">
<!-- REMOVED body HTML tag-->
       <div id="content">...</div>
       <aside>
          <div class="advert">..</div>
          <div class="news">..</div>
       </aside>
    <!-- End Container -->
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">..</div>
    <footer>..</footer>
<!--End Wrapper-->
</div>
```

[image]

## edit

Add bottom margin to your aside.

Comment: Try minimizing your window screen.  I attempted to apply the code to my site but it doesn't make a difference as the blue box is still touching the footer in all the browsers.

Comment: Any news or did you find your answer?

Comment: I found my answer, but the answer was that the clearfix should be placed before the end div.